# DataGridView Readonly "bug"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` to display some data. Some rows between data are `separator rows` so those are `readonly`. In some cases the whole `datagridview` might be `readonly`. But when I switch it back to `readonly = false`, all the rows are editable. Is it possible with out having to set again the `readonly` property of each row manually that my row came back as they were before?

Comment: Yeah ... sorry my bad I mean to set the cells who were readonly = false back to readonly = false and those readonly = true to readonly = true. My bad sorry it wasn't clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see using Reflector, setting `DataGridView.ReadOnly` to `true` will also set `ReadOnly` to `false` for all rows and columns in the grid - presumably it is assumed that you'll never subsequently want to set `DataGridView.ReadOnly` to `false` again.

So the only way I can see for you to get round this, is to "remember" which rows should be ReadOnly, for example by setting a suitable value in `DataGridViewRow.Tag`, then using this to restore the `ReadOnly` state manually.

For example, if you've set the `DataGridViewRow.Tag` property to `true` for readonly rows, you could handle the `DataGridView.ReadOnlyChanged` event with a handler that looks something like the following untested code:

```
void DataGridView_ReadOnlyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView) sender;
    if (!dataGridView.ReadOnly)
    {
        // DataGridView.ReadOnly has just been set to false, so we need to 
        // restore each row's readonly state.
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Tag != null && ((bool)row.Tag))
            {
                row.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it seems clear that the `DataGridView` isn't designed to allow its `ReadOnly` property to be toggled in that way.  Maybe you could design your application so that you don't ever need to set `DataGridView.ReadOnly` to `true`?

For example, if you want to prevent a user from editing by double-clicking on a cell, you could set `DataGridView.EditMode` to `DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgramatically` instead of setting `DataGridView.ReadOnly` to `true`.

Comment: Alternatively, I believe you can toggle `.Enabled` without changing the individual row `.ReadOnly` values.

Comment: @Ginosaji, See update, toggling `EditMode` is probably better than toggling `Enabled`, as presumably this will still allow you to select values from the grid.

Comment: I will try to look at EditMode

or I will have to loop again over all row to set them back as they are suposed to be

Comment: @Ginosaji I don't believe there is any enable on row/cell it's only at datagridview lvl

Comment: @im_a_noob: I mean use `Enabled` at the grid level and `ReadOnly` at the row/cell level so there's no conflict and they don't get overwritten. Though if `EditMode` works as Joe says it does, that would be an even better solution.

Comment: @Ginosaji Yeah the EditMode would be better for me because the user still can interact with the grid even if it's readonly

Comment: @joe I just tryed it and the `EditMode = EditProgramatically` does exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if the class is implemented by yourself then you can set your `DataGrid1.ReadOnly = true` and make the properties ReadOnly which needs to be ReadOnly.

like this:

```
string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
   get{return _myProperty;}
}
```

Comment: I didn't implemented the class... but the datagridview isn't bind. I fill it with my code

Comment: It's a pretty long code. I didn't really saw any use to post it so that's why i didn't included it in the original post

Comment: I suggest to create class for that and you can easily bind it to DataGrid or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill the DataGridView manually with code rather than binding it to a DataSource then you can simply set a row's readonly property to true when you add it.

If the above won't work then I don't understand what your code actually does, and like @Dilshod said it would be convenient if you posted it, or at least linked to a gist of it (http://www.gist.github.com).

Comment: this is what I do. I set the readonly property when I'm creating the row. But in some case the datagridview become readonly (all of it) but some user have the capacity to get it back to readonly = false and when they do that the whole grid become readonly = false even the row that weren't suposed to be editable at all